# Gear Fit SDK IllegalStateException

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I recently downloaded the Gear Fit-SDK from XDA-Developers-forum and tried the example in the pdf file.

The app is starting and I can click on the ListViewItem to start the ExampleDialog on my Gear Fit. But then I get the following error:

```
04-01 15:00:52.748  29498-29498/de.chrosey.gearfitone E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: de.chrosey.gearfitone, PID: 29498
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scup is not initialized
        at com.samsung.android.sdk.cup.ScupDialog.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at de.chrosey.gearfitone.cup.HelloCupDialog.<init>(HelloCupDialog.java:15)
        at de.chrosey.gearfitone.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:39)
        ...
```

Here are my files:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

String[] NAMES = {"Hello Cup"};
private HelloCupDialog mHelloCupDialog = null;

private static final int Hello_Cup = 0;
private ListView mListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, NAMES);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.demo_list);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            if (position == Hello_Cup) {
                if (mHelloCupDialog == null) {
                    mHelloCupDialog = new HelloCupDialog(
                            getApplicationContext());
                } else {
                    mHelloCupDialog.finish();
                    mHelloCupDialog = null;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}[...]}
```

HelloCupDialog.java

```
public class HelloCupDialog extends ScupDialog {

public HelloCupDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);                      //<-- this is where the error appears 
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    setBackEnabled(true);
    ScupLabel helloLabel = new ScupLabel(this);
    [...]
    setBackPressedListener(new BackPressedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed(ScupDialog scupDialog) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="de.chrosey.gearfitone">

<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.sdk.permission.SAMSUNG_CUP_SERVICE"/>

<application
    [...]
    <activity
        [...]
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.samsung.android.sdk.cup"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="SAMSUNG_CUP_APP"
        android:value="app_name;ic_launcher;true" />
</application>
```

I am testing on Samsung S4, Lollipop StockRom. IDE is Android Studio 1.1.

Has anybody an idea why it isn't working as other cups-enabled apps from PlayStore do?

Comment: same problem here, did you find a solution?

Comment: hmm, it seems as if this problem might be related to this one: http://markliebrand.blogspot.de/p/fixing-gear-fit-sdk-for-android-50.html
I tried the patch described there but it still crashes on Nexus 5/Marshmallow, now with another exception.

Comment: I have a Samsung Gear Fit SM-R350 watch and I want to enable debug on it as I want to develop an android app. What I've tried so far is pressing 7 times on Software Version in the About Gear Fit section but it does not work ... Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize Scup in your MainActivity before creating instance of ScupDialog. Add the following code after the setContentView.

```
Scup scup = new Scup();
    try {
        scup.initialize(this);
    }catch (Exception e){}
```

Hope this is clear!